# how to configure a database provider for DbContext?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a worker service in C#, target framework .NET 5.0.

Dependencies:

- microsoft.entityframeworkcore\5.0.12\
- microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design\5.0.12\
- microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver\5.0.12\
- microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\5.0.12\

When trying to read a table I'm running into the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

I will show you all relevant code and the appsettings.json.

appsettings.json:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Container": "Server=MY-PC\\SQL2019;Database=Container;User Id=abc;Password=abc;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  }
}
```

Program.cs:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;
                services.AddDbContext<ContainerContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Container")));
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });
}
```

Worker.cs:

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> logger;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // section1
            using (var context = new ContainerContext())
            {
                var test1 = context.MYTABLE.ToList();
            }

            // section2
            var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContainerContext>();
            optionBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Container"));
            using (var context = new ContainerContext(optionBuilder.Options))
            {
                var test2 = context.MYTABLE.ToList();                
            }

            await Task.Delay(300, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

ContainerContext.cs:

```cs
public partial class ContainerContext : DbContext
{
    public ContainerContext()
    {
    }

    public ContainerContext(DbContextOptions<ContainerContext> options):base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Please refer to the comments in Worker.cs.

Section1 results the mentioned exception at "var test1 = ...". In section2 I provide the DbContextOptions, and then it works.

But I should not need to provide the DbContextOptions every time I initiate a DbContext object.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You already configured the provider in the `AddDbContext` call. You can now inject `ContainerContext` into any class created through DI, including a worker service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provider is already configured in the `AddDbContext` call:

```
services.AddDbContext<ContainerContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
                           configuration.GetConnectionString("Container")));
```

`ContainerContext` can be injected into any class created through DI, including a worker service:

```
    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, ContainerContext db)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        _db=db;
    }
```

**Using scoped services in a Background Service**

The problem is that a DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, supposed to be short-lived and has to be disposed as soon as possible after use. That's why `AddDbContext` registers it as a scoped service. A `BackgroundService` on the other hand is a *singleton*. Only a single `ContainerContext` instance will ever be injected.

Handling this is described in [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) - instead of injecting the scoped service, inject `IServiceProvider`  and use it to create scopes as needed:

```
IServiceProvider services;
public Worker(IServiceProvider services,ILogger<Worker> logger)
{
    this.logger = logger;
    this.services=services;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // section1
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
           using (var context = scope.GetRequiredService<ContainerContext>())
           {
                var test1 = context.MYTABLE.ToList();
                ...
           }
        }
    }
}
```

When the scope is disposed, any instances created inside it will be disposed as well

**DbContextFactory in EF Core 5 and later**

The [AddDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontextfactory?view=efcore-5.0) method can be used to register an [IDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.idbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-5.0) that can create DbContext instances. The configuration is the same:

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<ContainerContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
                           configuration.GetConnectionString("Container")));
```

The code is one line shorter :

```
IDbContextFactory<ContainerContext> factory;
public Worker(IDbContextFactory<ContainerContext> factory,ILogger<Worker> logger)
{
    this.logger = logger;
    this.factory=factory;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // section1

        using (var context = factory.CreateDbContext())
        {
                var test1 = context.MYTABLE.ToList();
                ...
       }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Panagiotis. This is a bit more complicated than I was hoping for... Anyway my code won't compile now. At the line "using (var context = scope..GetRequiredService<ContainerContext>())" VS2019 says "CS1674: 'Range': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposible'. And CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScope' to 'System.Index'.

Comment: There was a typo `scope..GetRequiredService` should be `scope.GetRequiredService`. Somehow the compiler though that was a range operator????

Comment: As for complexity, that's only 2 lines compared to what you wrote. `// section1` won't work at all without hard-coding the settings and `// section2` replicates the DbContext configuration.

Comment: In EF Core 5 and later you can use a DbContextFactory. I added how to do that

Comment: Changed it to:
 using (var context = scope.GetRequiredService<ContainerContext>()), but now VS2019 says:
CS1929: 'IServiceScope' does not contain a definition for 'GetRequiredService' and the best extension method overload 'ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<ContainerContext>(IServiceProvider)' requires a receiver of type 'IServiceProvider'.

Comment: I also tried your DbContextFactory option and that works. Thank you very much for helping me out! (I had to remove one constructor in the ContainerContext object though, only this one is left: public ContainerContext(DbContextOptions<ContainerContext> options):base(options)
        {
        }